# Why is mod_python running entire django stack from beginning with each request?

Tags: django, mod-python

My understanding is that mod_python loads the python process into apache, avoiding the overhead of doing that on each call.  My expectation was that this would mean that my django stack would also only be loaded once.

What I am observing, however, is that every request is running the entire django stack from the beginning, as though it were the first request.  The settings are re-imported.  Middleware `__init__`'s, which are supposed to be run once at django startup, are run each time.  And so forth.  It seems to be essentially like I would expect CGI to be.

Is this expected behavior?  I have mostly worked with mod_wsgi, which I believe does not work this way, but I have to use mod_python for my current client.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache on UNIX systems is a multiprocess system as pointed out by someone else. Also make sure the MaxRequestsPerChild hasn't been set to be 1 in Apache configuration for some reason. Ideally that directive should be set to 0, meaning keep processes around and not recycle them based on number of requests.

Comment: Thanks Graham and Ignacio for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

It loads Django once per httpd process. Since multiple processes start (each child being a process), multiple instances of Django are started.